# Alignment of Button

Tags: android

I am in very beginning of Android.This is my first project.I have used a list view to display `EditText` and `TextView` side by side. Now I want a submit button at end.But if am using a `Button` view it is being displayed on every `EditText` instead.The following is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:text="subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />
<EditText
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:id="@+id/ScanText"
    android:hint="Internal+External"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
   android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/submitbutton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout which the `adapter` for `ListView` uses.The button is also being displayed as many times as there are `TextView`s.So how can I display only a single button at bottom.I got output as below.But I need only a single submit button at bottom

[this is the output i  got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAmpU.png)

I even tried placing button in my `main activity` below `ListView`.But it did'nt work.The below is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
 <ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"

    android:id="@+id/submitbutton"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your expected output!

Comment: Remove button from this layout, this layout is for list item. Add your button to the layout where listView is contained.

Comment: put the button in your activity layout instead--if u don't want the button to be created each time

Comment: Remove Submit button from your listview child xml and add it to your main_actviity.xml below ListView.

Comment: I did that but it is not at all visible.

Comment: have you add relative propertice  for your button to place in bottom of layout and below listview.

Comment: I placed list view in a linear layout and only for layout for edit text and textview are in relative layout

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change that :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
 <ListView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>

  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Submit"

      android:id="@+id/submitbutton"/>


  </LinearLayout>
```

(change the layout_height into wrap_content because with match_parent, it will take all tha place, so no more place for your button)

I am kind of new to android too so try this.

if it doesn't work, try to add this line :

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your ListView

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="submit"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```